# This webpage has a redirect loop when login Facebook by Firebase

Tags: firebase

Follow code worked fine with a user already authenticated with my facebook application. But throw a error:  "This webpage has a redirect loop" when use a new user.

```
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://tttb-demo.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myRootRef, function (error, user) {       
    });
auth.login('facebook', {
    rememberMe: true,
    scope: 'email,read_friendlists'
});
```

Comment: Two things stand out here: Have you configured your application to use `https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback` as your Facebook application site URL? Also, be sure that you're not using a `https://<your-firebase>-demo.firebaseio.com` Firebase (the "demo" server), but rather your actual production-configured Firebase, with your Facebook application id and secret configured in Forge under 'Auth'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

Either:
1) Take your app out of Sandbox mode on Facebook
or
2) Add the user to the list of developers on Facebook.

It's because only you are authorised to access it by default when you create an app in Facebook.